# Using WCF CloseAsync in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

Is this the right approach for closing connections with WCF in silverlight?

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();

        client.MakeRequestCompleted += (sender, e) =>
            {
                client.CloseAsync();

                //some implementation goes here
            };

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            client.MakeRequestAsync();
        }
```

I appear to be having problems related to concurrent connections, when the loop gets to the point where its made about 300 requests, it just fails. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but I've been researching a similar problem and no one else has left an answer...

You are closing your client without guaranteeing your operation to make 1000 web service calls has finished. I have also found it a little tough to find documentation on the `CloseAsync` method, but the [accepted wisdom](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/5546f5c2-55b4-4110-9c5e-4a234660e8b1) seems to be to call `CloseAsync` after you've made all your web service calls.

Also, making a thousand web service calls in your app could be dangerous - obviously I don't know the ins and outs of your situation but it may be better to combine your calls into fewer, larger operations.

Comment: I saw an implementation online that suggested adding "(e as ServiceClient).CloseAsync()" to the completed event, its worked ever since. I believe each asynchronous call is a unique connection to the web service that gets closed automatically but not immediately thereby creating a bottleneck causing the web service requests to fail. If you close each connection in the completed event then you prevent that bottleneck from occuring.

Comment: Yep, that's the way I'd do it normally but he's using one client object for 1000 concurrent operations. Who knows what's going to happen?

Answer (score 0):

This reference says that you don't have to close the request:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/29299/95656.aspx

---

```
1: ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
2: client.MakeRequestCompleted += (sender, e) =>...
3: client.MakeRequestAsync();
```

MakeRequestCompleted is a delegate. After a request is complete, the call is executed.

If you make lines 1 and 2 common for all the request, you have bind the same event with same arguments to every request. Then in your implementation code you don't really know which call caused which event. [1]

If you try to make just a line 1 common, you will have more and more events and you can't really unsubscribe in a thread safety way.

So, can you test how much performance is hit, if you just make all these lines for every request?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
    client.MakeRequestCompleted += (sender, e) =>...
    client.MakeRequestAsync();
}
```

(Then of course you should use a cache and use less requests.)

---

[1]: This may be ok if you construct just a "hammer-client" like this, but if you need some real implementation, common event args may not be enough.